# Docusaurus v2 change Navbar collapse breakpoint

Tags: docusaurus

With `Docusaurus v2`, I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction for figuring out how to change the breakpoint when the navbar collapses into mobile navbar (hamburger menu). Or just which component I might need to swizzle or whether it would just be a CSS thing? (Currently the navbar collapses at `996px` width, and I'd like it to collapse at more like `600px`.) Thanks for any leads!

Comment: I used this to override some styles https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout#global-styles Maybe you can solve your issue with breakpoints as well